# How macro defintion works for memory leak detection?

Tags: c++, memory, macros, memory-leaks

The simple way to detect memory leak is to use DEBUG_NEW macro which is defined as follows

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#define DEBUG_NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#endif
```

I found a function operator new which is defined as follows:

```
void* __cdecl operator new(size_t nSize, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine);
```

How can `new(__FILE__, __LINE__)` be replaced in `new(size_t nSize, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine`)  here?

Can anyone explain how this macro definition works?

Comment: Yeeek. This will do terrible things if anybody tries to use placement new, or declare/define a class's allocation routine. Don't redefine keywords.

Comment: Placement new is also very bad practice. No one actually uses placement new in code. Can you please explain how this macro definition works in general? I am interested to know how it works?

Comment: "No one actually uses placement new in code." Wrong.

Comment: Well, I want to know how this macro definition works? Could you please explain that instead of saying this is not good?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are three definition of `new` in C++ standard:

```
throwing (1)  void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);
nothrow (2)   void* operator new (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) throw();
placement (3) void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) throw();
```

First one throws an `std::bad_alloc` exception on failure, but the second one returns a null-pointer on failure. Third one is placement new.

For `new int`, the compiler will generate a call to `operator new(sizeof(int))`.

The `nothrow_value` parameter is only used to distinguish it from the first version with an overloaded version.

```
MyClass * p2 = new (std::nothrow) MyClass;
```

It allocates memory by calling: `operator new (sizeof(MyClass),std::nothrow)` and then constructs an object at the newly allocated space.

So when we write the following code

```
MyClass * p2 = new(__FILE__, __LINE__) MyClass;
```

We actually call `operator new (sizeof(MyClass), __FILE__, __LINE__)`. This is what I wanted to know. 
Thanks everyone for help.

The other definitions are:

```
__FILE__
```

This macro expands to the name of the current input file, in the form of a C string constant. This is the path by which the preprocessor opened the file, not the short name specified in #include or as the input file name argument. For example, "/usr/local/include/myheader.h" is a possible expansion of this macro.

```
__LINE__
```

This macro expands to the current input line number, in the form of a decimal integer constant. While we call it a predefined macro, it's a pretty strange macro, since its "definition" changes with each new line of source code.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ language prohibits definition of any macro whose name is lexically identical to a keyword.  Since `new` is a keyword, defining a macro named `new` is prohibited.  Your compiler may reject a program with such a macro definition, or your program may exhibit unexpected behavior at compile- or run-time.

So, let's consider a well-formed alternative that uses the same macro trickery:

```
#define my_new DEBUG_NEW
#define DEBUG_NEW my_new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

These macros rely on the fact that macro replacement is non-recursive.  Let's consider an example use of `my_new`:

```
my_new T;
```

First, `my_new` is identified as a macro and is replaced by its replacement list, `DEBUG_NEW`.  Then the replacement list is re-scanned for additional macros to replace.  `DEBUG_NEW` is identified as a macro and is replaced by its replacement list, `my_new(__FILE__, __LINE__)`.

At this point, the replacement of the original `my_new` is still being evaluated, so the new instance of `my_new` in the replacement list is not macro replaced again, so it is left as `my_new`.  This ensures that there is no opportunity for recursion (or infinite recursion) during macro replacement.  `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are identified as macros and are replaced by the appropriate values, yielding a final result of:

```
my_new("clyde.cpp", 42) T;
```

Comment: I knew that, but I wanted to know more. Thanks for answering

Comment: You asked, "can anyone explain how this macro definition works?"  This is how the macro definition works.  If this isn't what you wanted to know, what did you want to know?  More about what?

Comment: I answered in my following answer what I was searching. Please check it out. What you explain - every programmer should know that. Thanks.